# NP-hardness of language of graphs with $\alpha(G)=n/3$

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

How to prove the NP-hardness of the language $\{G \mid \alpha(G) =\frac{1}{3} |V(G)|\}$?

Here $G$ is a graph, $V(G)$ is its vertex set, and $\alpha(G)$ is the independence number of $G$, which is the maximum size of an independent set.

Comment: I don't understand the notation you are using, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language is no help. What do each of the symbols mean?

Comment: I guess the notations for the language are "The set of graphs such that the independence number is a third of the number of vertices"? It would be better to re-define the notations in the question.

Comment: Thanks @integrator. In that case: Think about what you can do to an arbitrary input graph that will change the number of vertices to whatever you want (thereby giving you control over the target IS size) while having only a limited effect on the size of the maximum IS in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

1-IN-3SAT is the following problem: given a 3SAT instance, determine whether there is a truth assignment in which each clause contains *exactly* one true literal. It is known that 1-IN-3SAT is NP-complete.

Given an instance of 1-IN-3SAT, construct an instance of your problem in which each clause corresponds to a triangle, and contradicting literals are connected by edges. Details left to you.